# build gridview with variable column number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I have data in a sql table that looks like this:

```
Name    colno    remark
----    -----    ------
bill    col 1    good
bill    col 2    ok
bill    col 3    triff
bill    col 4    A1
bob     col 1    poor
bob     col 2    excellent
bob     col 3    ok
bob     col 4    B+
bert    col 1    
bert    col 2    no info
bert    col 3    pass
bert    col 4    C-
```

and I want a gridview (?) with databinding that's laid out like this:

```
Name     col 1    col 2      col 3    col 4
Bill     good      ok        triff     A1
Bob      poor     excellent  ok        B+
bert              no info    pass      C-
```

So I can edit/insert data as needed.

The killer is that the number of columns can vary, eg I've 4 in the first example above, but it can be any number between 10 - 15. Hence on a second extract the data might look like this:

```
Name    colno    remark
----    -----    ------
brenda  col 1    ok
brenda  col 2    ok
brenda  col 3    excellent
boris   col 1    poor
boris   col 2    ok
boris   col 3    ok
baz     col 1    great
baz     col 2    no info
baz     col 3    ok
```

Giving a table like this:

```
Name     col 1    col 2      col 3
brenda   ok        ok        excellent
boris    poor      ok          ok
baz      great    no info      ok
```

I've explored sql pivot but I don't want the data summarised in any way, it's just a single field of text per record. So I don't think this kind of query will work:

```
select * from myData
pivot (someAggregateFunctionThatIDontNeed(colNo) for colNo_ButNotBeingAggregated in (variableNoOfColumns)) as notAnAvergageJustText
```

I've tried to build a DataTable piecemeal from multiple sql-extracts-into-datatables-then-loop (that works, kinda, but I can't figure out how to bind the data after)

Any ideas? I've caned this for four days and I'm stumped. The offer of the wifey coming round to cook your Sunday dinner is still on...

Comment: workingclassmedia, could you show an example of what the file would look like with the varying data , layout..? sounds like you will need to do something like a control break, then if you find the key work item4 after the first read..you know that you have the columns and the data.. then from there you read / check item1...item4 do a skip on the word item1..item4 and then save the data.. does this make sense..? you could also put that data into an string[] and do checking on the data that way.. or a List<string>

Comment: The number of columns per sql select stays the same, but will vary on each extract - I'll edit my post above to expand.

Comment: let me rephrase the question, where is this initial data stored originally / coming from..? a database table or a file..?

Comment: Hi DJ, just edited my post to explain data is from a sql table, and added original column headings - not sure if this helps?

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot. Look up "pivot" MSDN for SQL, or google it. Be prepared to spend a little time getting you head round it, the syntax is not straightforward.

Comment: Hi Ian, I started with pivot but this doesn't seem to be the right way to go, as I don't want the data summarised (they're individual comments that I still want to be able to add/edit) and also I want the grid databound at the end so I can update the original table - or am I using pivot incorrectly?

Comment: Ian, added my pivot example to my post above - let me know if you think you can get it to work...

Comment: In that case, binding is going to be difficult. You really need to get each "item" into its own entity with "name" "value (comment)" and colNr , probably as <XML> or a temp table. Then use a select Distinct to find the number of coumns and create a dynamic query on your temp table and create specific update statements for the cells picking up Name and colNr as params...Then bind your grid to the result

Comment: Cheers Ian, this is the route I've already started down, but strewth it's fiddly. I can't upvote your answer so far (not enough rep. Grrr), any ideas why my question was downvoted? I thought it was useful, clear, showed research effort etc... The requirement is actually reasonably common in education - you set a unit up, the number of criteria for that unit will be different from another unit, yet when you come to mark it you want a grid for just that unit, with names down the left and that unit's criteria along the top.

Comment: In fact, now I've thought about it, surely this is a regular requirement for anyone with variable-columns spreadsheets that they need to chuck in/out of a db? Dunno... and still not sure why my question got a downvote, but there we are...

Comment: Hi I have the same "issue" when a user can return a variable number of columns depending on a date range. What I do then is convert the variable number to an xml string inside the query, bind to the query and then parse out xml inside the net script and bind to the result

Comment: Grr, ok Ian - I've temporarily 'cured' this by doing the following steps:from a sql query that extracts the column names and then iterates through these to build the column names of a temp

Comment: Grr, ok Ian - I've temporarily 'cured' this by doing the following steps: 1) upload a csv that has the students down one side and colnames across the top, with comments in the cells - this gets dumped into a DataTable 2) iterate through the DataTable and build rows that have the student name as row[0], the rowNo as row[1] and cellcontents as row[2] - its a loop in a loop. A complete dog's dinner, but it works. Someone out there must have cracked this in a more elegant manner - maybe the person who downvoted my question? If you want the code I can post it but I warn you it's spaghetti...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ISNULL in your SQL statement to check for columns that have no data?  If there is no data, you can set a default setting in the statement itself.

```
ISNULL([YOUR FIELD],'Whatever you want to display here')
```

Comment: Hi illinoistim - will check tonight when I'm back, but that seems to make sense - at this stage I'm just trying to get the grid to build automatically and I'll worry about the binding later...

Comment: illinoistim - this is proving to be a nightmare - see my comments below to IanP - I've sort of solved it by knocking up the data in a spreadsheet (brittle), saving as CSV, importing into a DataTable, then loop in a loop to build another DT, then squirting that DT into the sql database - spaghetti mess. Someone must have done this in a slicker manner...all insights welcome!

Comment: Personally, if you are able to build better SQL Tables, I would separate this table into at least 2 different tables.  If you are unable to do this, I would just use the ISNULL sytax for every column.  This way, it can be left empty in your table.  In order to get the results that you want, you might need to loop through your table using the WHERE statement.  Then you can segment out WHERE [Name]="Brenda" for example.